# manage to access (work on) a new Magento install using the same domain as a live production store on a completely diffrent hosting acc (different IP)

Tags: hosting, domain

I have 2 hosting accounts - an old VPS account and a new CLOUD account. I have an old version of Magento (1,3,1) running on the old VPS hosting account (this needs to be the active one because I have all my products there and it is the current production store). I want to upgrade by just doing a fresh install of the Magento 1,9,1 version so I created a new MYDOMAIN.com account on the cloud server and then I installed the new Magento shopping cart there (1,9,1). I planned to access that by using the IP address (numerical IP address and then the account user name) but now - when I click on the IP address in the list of hosting accounts in the WHM (basically just try to access the new shopping cart by it's actuall IP address and a user name on the server) - it automatically loads the actual MYDOMAIN.com website (on the old server). I mean - the old website suppose to be the one active (loading from the VPS hosting account) but at the same time - I need to work on the new version of the shopping cart before it's all ready to go live (change design, add hundreds of products etc.)

How can I work with this new version of the Magento shopping cart without it reverting to the (old) production site?

Thanks,

Allysin

PS: Is this something in the htaccess file or something like that?

PS2: The hosting company replied this but I don't really understand it...

The easiest way to work on your new Magento site is to create a subdomain within your account MYDOMAIN.com .
You will have to create new folder within public_html or wherever you like and call it, for example test.

Then, within your cPanel account merge that subdomain with created folder and you can start testing.
Of course, you will have to copy content to newly created folder.

I cannot have a special directory where Magento resides I think because of the SEO links would not be the same as in the old store...

**Thanks again for any suggestions. ;-)**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It could be a couple if things in case it is Magento related.

- Check the `.htaccess` file for references to the old domain and comment out those lines with `#`
- Check the `core_config_data` table in the database for the `base_url`. Make sure that's set to the IP address. There can be several entries for the `base_url` so do a thorough search.
- Disable and clear cache. The configuration for the old `base_url` could be stored in the cache
- Clean your browser cache (just to be sure)
- Check the `index.php` for any references to the old domain. Shouldn't be there but i've come across hacked in redirects there

If none of those come up with results it's probably some setting in the servers configuration. With that, I'm afraid, I cannot help you

Comment: Hi Sander, Thank you so much for your answer! I really appreciate it... I checked the .htaccess and as this is a fresh install - there were no references to MYDOMAIN.com in there. I found 2 references in the core_config_data in the database - one of them is for the secure base URL and the other is for the unsecure base URL - both being currently set to http://www.EXAMPLE.COM What do you think I should change these to? Just the IP address or the IP/~userHOSTINaccountNAME ? Thanks you so much - you are so cool! ;-)

Comment: Hi Allysin, the base urls should be set to the URL you would access your shop. It depends heavily on how the server is configured. If it's a VPS as you stated the IP should probably work. If you're not sure ask your hosting provider what the value should be.

Comment: OK - nothing in the .htaccess or index.php! I changed the entries in the core_config_data and deleted the Cache on my computer. I don't really know how to delete the Cache in the new Magento install (I can't really login to the Admin panel because it resolves back to the old Magento install) - I bet I could just delete the Cache folder via FTP? Any other suggestions? :-(

Comment: Yup, you can. Just throw away the content in the `var/cache` folder. Might be easier to do it via the command line tho

Comment: That WORKS!!! Thank you, thank you, thank you! Now I have to do my work quickly (I have to transfer all 1000 and some products from the old Magento version 1.3.1 to the new 1,9,1 because Google is threatening me that if the site is NOT 100% mobile complient by April 21st - they will remove me from search! :-( Is there any way to export the products from the old 1,3,1 database and IMPORT them into the new one?

Comment: Hm actually Google is not going to remove you, just giving a small penalty but it's just one of the points they're checking for amongst others. 
Anyway, moving from 1.3 to 1.9 is always a good idea ;)

So the easiest way is probably making a product CSV export and importing it with Avs_FastSimpleImport but since the versions are so different i'm not sure if the data is completely compatible

Comment: One last question - I installed the access shop responsive theme and I thought I could just block out the front page from being visible by DISABLING the CMS pages in CMS - Pages but it does not take all the contect off....Is there a really simple way to make the Magento shopping cart NOT show the front page while I work on adding the products on the back end? Thanks a million! :-*

Comment: haha no problem. Not sure if you can easily disable the cart. I normally put the demo notice up on dev sites and set the robots to noindex nofollow. Both are under `System > Configuration > Design > Head`

Comment: nah, just worked on waaay to much shops. glad to be able to help you